# Hacer en un menú en C++

Tags: c++, menú

tengo una duda. Estoy haciendo un programa el cual consiste en un menú en C++ para realizar ciertas operaciones, sin embargo al querer correr el programa, no compila y me marca errores, chequé el código para ver si había algún error de tipeo o al declarar variables pero no. Quisiera saber en qué me estoy equivocando, por favor y gracias. Adjunto código.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int opcion,num;
    
   float numero,cubo; 
   
   cout<<"\t Menú"<<endl;
   
    cout<<"1) Obtener el cubo del número"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"2) Determinar si el número es par e impar"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"3) Salir"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Teclea para la opción deseada"; cin>>opcion;
    
    switch(opcion){
        
        case 1: 
        
        cout<<"Escribe un número"; cin<<numero;
        
        cubo=pow(numero,3);
        
        cout<<"El resultado es: "<<cubo;break;
        
        case 2:
        
        cout<<"Escribe un número"; cin<<num;
        
        if(num%2==0){
            
            cout<<"\nEl número es par"<<endl;
            
        }
        
     else{
         
         cout<<"\nEl número es impar"<<endl;
         
     } break;   
        
     case 3:break;
        
    }
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*el programa, no compila y me marca errores*" por favor, si tienes errores en tu código compártelos, no podemos ayudarte a corregir unos errores que sólo ves tú.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` es un operador de entrada, es decir, permite introducir valores al programa.

La operación que haces entonces es **extraer** elementos de `cin`. El operador de extracción es `>>` y no `<<` como aparece en tu código:

```
cout<<"Escribe un número"; cin<<numero;
//                            ~~ <<--- AQUI

cout<<"Escribe un número"; cin<<num;
//                            ~~ <<--- AQUI
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había fijado, ahora sí ya me corrió.